# Does the cost of reviving a dweller ever change? If so, how much?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Yesterday I sent an explorer out to the wastes and he died at the end of the day. I paid 300 caps to revive him and brought him back to the vault.

Today I sent him again and almost certainly he will die once more (brilliant overseeing, eh?). Should I expect to fork over even more caps today? If so, how much?

In case it matters (as per Rapitor's comments), he will probably level up a few times before he dies today. He was revived at level 19 and he will probably be 20 or 21 today.

More generally, is the cost of revival related to anything at all? Is it related to any of those factors:

- the dweller's level or their SPECIAL attributes?
- the number of times that particular dweller has already been revived?
- the overall number of times dwellers have been revived?

I have had a few dwellers dying in my vault, but I just didn't keep track of the cost trend. I've searched the Internet, but I couldn't find anything about it either.

Comment: I think it costs more to revive them the higher level they are, but I haven't really been having to deal with too much death to confirm

Comment: I paid 1000 for a level 50 which stats weren't that much better than before, so it seems level is the main or only factor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The price for reviving a dweller inside your vault is based on the level of the dweller.

The higher the level of the dweller the more expensive.

But it caps out at 1000 caps.

According to [this wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fallout-shelter/Dwellers) the formula is as following:

> their revive cost scales to the level starting at 100 CAPS for level
>   1, and increases an additional +20 CAPS for each level afterwards.

That would mean the cap is reached when the dweller hits level 46.

For dwellers in the wasteland it is a bit different.

As you can see it will cost 1000 caps to revive this level 29:
[image]

I am unsure the exact math for this, but the cost is still capped at 1000 caps for dwellers.

Comment: I think the exception is Mr Handy, as I recall him being low level, high cost.

Comment: Mr Handy is always 2000 caps, and I don't think he levels up.

Comment: While this is useful, and has a nice picture, the death referred to in the question was while exploring the wasteland. At least we know the cap, I guess.